# Update Alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: updates

I am going to re-install Ubuntu , is there any alternative way to to re-install Ubuntu & full Update Or do  i have to update almost 500 to 600 MB online ?

right now my Ubuntu 11.10 Fully updated , is there any Alternative cauzz i dint want to download 5 to 6 Hundred MB online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### **Thats is very simple & easy task**

1. create a tar /var/cache/apt/archives

```
 tar cvf archives.tar /var/cache/apt/archives
```

2. now backup `archives.tar`

3. Now Install Ubuntu

4. After Installing Ubuntu **check for updates** & **close it**

5. now extract `archives.tar` at  `/var/cache/apt/`

```
sudo tar xvf archives.tar /var/cache/apt/
```

6. i did a reboot ( Dont know may be Optional )

7. Now check for Updates they will **0 MB to Download** OR may be some **kb's**

> **Verified & Checked on 1 host OS & 5 VM's**

---

**A GUI based solution**

```
sudo nautilus
```

[image]

make a tar & then backup

Install Ubuntu & Check for Update & Close it

[image]

after that again open terminal &  `sudo nautilus`

[image]

open archieve.tar & Drag Drop it As shown in pic

& then again Check for Update , it will be **0 MB**

Comment: This assumes the cache still contains everything, and that he has not run apt-get clean, etc.

Comment: i did once & see what it did then i have never ever done apt-get clean

Comment: i test things alot , so thats why i need it