# How do I back up the list of applications I have installed?

Tags: backup

I have very slow internet connection. It sometimes manages to reach as high as 20 KBps!! Installing large packages like K3B or wine or some games takes takes too much time. If ever somehow I want to reinstall Ubuntu then I have to reinstall all this packages which is pain. So how to backup this application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out AptOnCD ([aptoncd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aptoncd) [image: Install Aptoncd] ).

```
sudo apt-get install aptoncd
```

Comment: Hey AptOnCD is quite very old. Is the project abandoned??

Comment: Not very sure, but it works great if you are playing with same OS (freshly installed)

Comment: Check this - http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, aptonCD will do that, If you want to backup them manually, just copy the /var/cache/ap/archives directory.And in the new system, Just copy the backed up cache and overwrite the same directory with root permissions, use synaptic to install those (But you will have to install dependencies manually) But if you have deleted the cache recently, you won't get them!.If you have windows intalled and use a wubi installation, just backup the wubi root file elsewhere. I think that's the best method to backup your system and make experiments on ubuntu!

Comment: What if I use AptOnCD?? Do i have to install dependencies then??

Comment: If you use aptoncd(click on the link - it will install automatically) , you neednot do anything else

Comment: @mac i thought Even in the Aptoncd, I have to install dependencies. Thanks so much

Comment: Check whit - http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/

Comment: All dependencies you installed will be in same folder which aptoncd back up. So next time when you use aptoncd (on same OS installed on different machine) the dependencies will be picked up and installed. However in some cases, you might not be able to do 100% backup

Comment: Can we install packages or updates to other offline computer using this app?

Answer (score 1):

> #### **Thats is very simple & easy task**

1. create a tar /var/cache/apt/archives

```
 tar cvf archives.tar /var/cache/apt/archives
```

2. now backup `archives.tar`

3. Now Install Ubuntu

4. After Installing Ubuntu **check for updates** & **close it**

5. now extract `archives.tar` at  `/var/cache/apt/`

```
sudo tar xvf archives.tar /var/cache/apt/
```

6. i did a reboot ( Dont know may be Optional )

7. Now check for Updates they will **0 MB to Download** OR may be some **kb's**

> **Verified & Checked on 1 host OS & 5 VM's**

---

**A GUI based solution**

```
sudo nautilus
```

[image]

make a tar & then backup

Install Ubuntu & Check for Update & Close it

[image]

after that again open terminal &  `sudo nautilus`

[image]

open archieve.tar & Drag Drop it As shown in pic

& then again Check for Update , it will be **0 MB**

[Update Alternative for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104364/update-alternative-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

If u want to backup the list of installed packages here are some script for you that will make it easy for you, first to create packages.list there is a python script to do that.
[create_package_list.py](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1047632/).This script will create a packagelist.txt that will have all the packages you have installed currently.Next there are two shell script, [autoaptitude.sh](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1047609/) and [autoaptget.sh](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1047613/). Keep all of these scripts and the packages.list in backup in Ubuntu-one, Dropbox etc.And whenever you need to get all the previously installed packages run the scripts and your work will be done.