# How can I install apps previously installed on a different installation on my new installation?

Tags: updates, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I back up the list of applications I have installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120271/how-do-i-back-up-the-list-of-applications-i-have-installed)

On my new 12.04 installation i want to install apps that reside on my 11.10 installation without having to download them again.is that possible?

Comment: Why would you not want to download them again? Any specific applications?

Comment: I don't want to download them again because i have a very slow internet.
And yes, I still have my 11.10 installation on a different partition.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible for some but it's likely that the version of the apps available for 12.04 are different than those that were available when 11.10 was released.

It would also depend on whether you still had the .deb available in the apt cache in order to copy it, you would also need to check dependencies.

You can search for packages here and see if the versions are the same.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Some idea of which packages you are talking about would help.

Answer (score 0):

It is partially possible, You can use aptoncd for it

1. Install aptoncd on both 11.10 and 12.04
2. backup the cache from 11.10 using aptoncd
3. Install synaptic in 12.04 and extract it using aptoncd
4. Install the softwares using software centre

**WARNING :aptoncd is for same version of ubuntu only only so it wont work on most of the packages**

[image]