# How to import settings and files from old HD/smaller to new HD/1TB

Tags: settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move home folder to second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive)

I upgraded from a smaller HD to a larger HD, for now I have both HD's, but plan on getting rid of the older HD...  also the newer drive is a dual boot with windows.

I waited for the import settings and files part of the new install on the new HD to come up, and it did come up, but it showed absolutely nothing.

So now I need to figure out a way to import all those settings and files and etc... so I can take the older/smaller drive off of this box.

I now have two copies of Ubuntu 12.04, one on the older/smaller drive and one on the newer/larger drive.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/q/21321/12864)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can take an iamge of your old system using Clonezilla and
   restore it on your new HD.

   Download Clonezilla iso file from [here](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) then burn it to a CD and
   from this live Cd you can do what you want
2. You can also use something else like ghost for linux but Clonezilla
   is the best
3. Else you can use AptoCD to backup applications you've installed on
   the old HD and restore on the new HD. 
   `http://askubuntu.com/questions/120271/how-do-i-back-up-the-list-of-applications-i-have-installed`